# netbackup port openinings - does it require bi-directional communication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

Our backup guy asked me to open up a firewall ticket to open up connections from our terrestrial data center to AWS. He asked for ports 1556, 13782, 13724 to be opened up bi-directional between the backup server in our data center to the subnets in AWS.

My question is, why is he asking for bi-directional communication? Usually I open up the firewall from the source device to the destination and the firewall allows for bi-directional communication.

He claims that the communication can be initiated by either side. Is he right about that? Because if he's not, I'd like to save some work for both myself and the firewall team.

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional Communication will be needed as Private Branch Exchange will not work without it. More over to transmit data from Client to Master server 2 way communication is needed. Firewall Plays a role in it but still Ports needs to be opened bidirectionally.

If you have any query please let me know.